# Bottom Alignment Constraints Not Working in IB - Items move above or below each other depending on device

Tags: storyboard, constraints

I am trying to lay out some labels and a button relative to the bottom of the safe area in a storyboard. I don't understand these constraints at all.

I have a button which is stays in the correct place across devices. It's constraints are 
Session List Button.Bottom = Safe Area.Bottom - 32, priority 1000
Session List Button.CenterX = Save Area.Center X

Then I have have a UILabel that I want to go just above the button. It's constraints are
Subtitle Label.Bottom = Safe Area.Bottom - 72, priority 998
Subtitle Label.Width = Safe Area.Width

The label doesn't stay above the button when I change devices in IB. It moves all over the place - sometimes way above or way below the button.

I don't understand why the views don't move when I change the constraints in their constraints, so that might be a clue as to what I am missing.

I have also tried the same constraints relative to the superview and the background but also got unpredictable results.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue is just a bug in IB. When I run the app the constraints seem to work correctly.